# How do we use Maginos's staff if it's a blunt melee weapon?

Tags: mice-and-mystics

If Mice and Mystic's Maginos is equipped with *Maginos' Staff*, it is normally a ranged weapon with +1 to ranged attacks.  Paired with Maginos's battle value of 1, it seems for normal ranged attacks we should roll 2 dice.

However, *Maginos' Staff* states:

> When attacking a figure that is on the same space as this mouse, this staff is considered a blunt melee weapon.

What does that mean for attacks made by Maginos against enemies in the same space?  Does he roll 2 dice?  Or does he only roll 1 die, because the staff only grants +1 ranged but not +1 melee?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You roll 2 dice and must use a melee attack to attack a minion in the same space with the staff.**

The section you quoted is the cards **Ability**. (page 4 pdf, page 2 rule book)

> 4) Ability: any special rules that apply to the card are described here.

That special rule requires that you may only use it to perform melee attacks on minions in your same space, but normally the rules do not prevent this.

Item bonuses add to the number of dice you roll when performing a specific type of attack. Ranged attacks count bow symbols as hits, melee attacks count sword symbols as hits. Nothing in [the rules](http://www.plaidhatgames.com/images/games/mice-and-mystics/mmrulebook.pdf) prevents you from using a ranged attack on a minion in the same space as your mouse.

> **Melee Attack** - [...] Then roll a number of action dice equal to that mouse’s battle value. Remember to **add any bonuses that the mouse’s items or equipped weapons might give it**.
>
> **Ranged attack** - If a mouse is armed with a ranged weapon or spell, it can perform a ranged attack. Ranged attacks are performed in the same way as melee attacks, **except each bow symbol counts as a hit instead of the sword or sword/
>   shield symbol**. Also, when selecting a target for the attack, a player can select any minion on the same room tile as the attacking mouse as long as that mouse can ‘see’ the target. However, **if there are minions in the same or adjacent space as the mouse, one of those nearby minions must be selected as the target of the attack.** (page 13 pdf, page 11 rule book)

The [FAQ](http://www.plaidhatgames.com/images/games/mice-and-mystics/mmfaq.pdf) and the designer [further clarified](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/9355581#9355581) that Maginos gets the +1 from the staff regardless of whether he is performing a melee or ranged attack.

> *1.1.5: When attacking a minion in the same space using Maginos' staff, do you still get the bonus listed on the card for a ranged attack?*
>
> **A: Yes, just imagine that the bow changes into a sword any time Maginos shares a space with minions.**
>
> *Q: about maginos' staff. It has a +1 on top of a range symbol in the top corner. Does the staff still give a bonus to melee combat, or only to ranged because that's what the +1 is over?*
>
> **A: It adds to his battle any time he uses it to do a battle action. The +1 just signifies that it is a bonus to his battle, the bow shows that it hits on bows and can be used at a distance. The weapon special ability breaks this rule a bit and allows him to hit on swords/sword shields when attacking an enemy in the same space. Usually, when you use a ranged weapon, it only hits on bows even if you use it on an enemy in the same or adjacent space.**

Comment: Why 1 dice? As far as I can see, the +1 of the staff still counts.

Comment: According to the OP, the card says, "Maginos' Staff, it is normally a ranged weapon with **+1 to ranged attacks.**" I don't have the card in front to verify, but presumably the bonus applies specifically to ranged attacks.

Comment: And here I wonder: where does it state that the bonus of a weapon counts only for the ranged attack?

Comment: @Arne, corrected with designer and FAQ reference.

Answer (score 2):

The rule book says that you add as many dice as the bonus of your chosen weapon to your base attack. It does not specify to discern between a ranged bonus or melee bonus in this case.

Maginos' Staff has this feature in favor of the player: with a melee attack, you have a chance of 3/6 of rolling a successful attack, instead of 2/6 in a ranged attack.

Also this means that you cannot cast a ranged spell on an enemy on your own space. Instead you beat it with the staff.

Edit: Source for the +1 in Melee: MM FAQ (http://www.plaidhatgames.com/images/games/mice-and-mystics/mmfaq.pdf)

Comment: I see no prohibition in the rules from attacking your own space with a ranged attack.

Comment: Hm, interesting. I imagined that your spells would be cast using the staff. If not, then you're right. If they are, I think the rule in Mag Roader's question counts: "When attacking a figure that is on the same space as this mouse, this staff is considered a blunt melee weapon."

Comment: You can attack someone in the same space using a ranged attack, but this particular staff is not a ranged weapon *if* there's an enemy in your space.